# open files sequentially and search for content match in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl.

I am comfortable with opening two files and checking their contents, but how do I open files one after another in a loop and check their contents?

Comment: Store the all file names in an array. Then iterate the loop for this array. Then open the file and read it

Answer (score 2):

As [mkHun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030973/open-files-sequentially-and-search-for-content-match-in-perl/39031159#comment65412180_39030973),  you can use an array to store filenames then loop over it. See the below template to get an idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @files = qw(file.txt file2.txt file3.txt filen.txt);
foreach my $file (@files){
    #open file in read mode to check contents
    open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Couldn't open file $!";
    #loop over file's content line by line
    while(<$fh>){
        #$_ contains each line of file. You can manipulate $_ below
        if($_ =~ /cat/){
            print "Line $. contains cat";   
        };
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Also read:

- [Loop Control in Perl (perlsyn)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control)

Comment: There is no need to close file handle in your script  because it will automatically close by the lexical file handle :)

Comment: Right. But since OP is new to Perl, I thought it'd be nice to be explicit about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i need to compare the contents of the files .so at same point of time i need to open two files and compare. in the above solution u mentioned i can only open one file at a time and compare with a string .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chankey Pathak's answer, if you want to iterate over files in some directory (meaning you don't know what are the names of the files you want to process, but you know their location), the [`File::Find`](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPtOj488zOAhUFvRQKHYsWA-AQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fperldoc.perl.org%2FFile%2FFind.html&usg=AFQjCNF6oM_MS5oJQ8Qp9QhQ3QLaSOOf5Q&sig2=DmxDerTHfWh_9erK2cF9kg) module is an easy and straightforward solution.